# how to create a cell browser in GWT

Tags: gwt

I am trying to create a cell browser , gettign help from [GWT Showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellBrowser)

Here i am creating CellBrowser

```
        final MultiSelectionModel<MyDTO> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<MyDTO>();

        CellBrowser cellBrowser = new CellBrowser(new ContactTreeViewModel(selectionModel), null);
```

What i am not getting is that , What is ContactTreeViewModel? I have read the class contacttreeviewmodel in GwtShowcase , but couldnt understand, what is it exactly

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your *view model*, that is the interface between the tree view and your actual model (in MVC or MVP parlance). The `CellBrowser` (same for a `CellTree`) will ask your `TreeViewModel` for the nodes of the tree (in the form of `NodeInfo` objects), their children, how to display them (the associated `Cell`), how to *select* them (the associated `SelectionModel`: you can have a tree where you can only select nodes from the 2nd level, and/or only one node per *branch* at the 2nd level, or any node, or ...), and finally how to update them (the `ValueUpdater`).

Basically (disclaimer: this is a simplification of the process!), each level in the tree is a `CellList` that a `NodeInfo` is responsible for. The `setDataDisplay` associates that `CellList` with the `NodeInfo` so that changes to the model can be reflected in the tree, then the `Cell`, `ProvidesKey`, `SelectionModel` and `ValueUpdater` all have the same behavior as for a `CellList`. The `CellBrowser` asks your `NodeInfo` for them in order to setup the `CellList`. When expanding a node, the `CellBrowser` asks your `TreeViewModel` for the `NodeInfo` associated to the expanded node and uses it to create a new `CellList`.

The `ContactTreeViewModel` from the Showcase is thus a specific implementation of the `TreeViewModel` to display contacts (the model) as a tree.

Answer (score 0):

The GWT showcase is an example of what you can do with code samples.

I think you should read the documentation of cell widgets before trying to understand such a code from scratch.

Here is the documentation, read it, and retry to understand the code.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#available